# Why is mixed content on google chrome not working

Tags: html, google-chrome, http, https, mixed-content

I have a site that is loaded over secure connection (`https://`). I have a href to `http://` that downloads a file. I want to use the mixed content solution here(I know I should do https:// but for now I want to use `http://`). So for the fix I added `<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="upgrade-insecure-requests">` to the head. For some reason I still get the Mixed Content error in google chrome. My current chrome version is 88.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Security-Policy/upgrade-insecure-requests):

> The HTTP `Content-Security-Policy` (CSP) `upgrade-insecure-requests` directive instructs user agents to treat all of a site's insecure URLs (those served over HTTP) as though they have been replaced with secure URLs (those served over HTTPS).

That directive does *not* allow mixed content. It just treats all `http:` links as if they were `https:` links (e.g. if a link which points to `http://google.com/` is clicked, the browser navigates to `https://google.com/`). The only ways (AFAIK) to allow mixed content are to either:

- serve your content via plain HTTP, or
- allow mixed content manually in the site's settings.

Comment: So, the best option is to use https:// in the href then? meaning avoid mixed content.

Comment: If what you are saying is correct then why am I getting this error?
`Mixed Content: The site at https://xxxx was loaded over a secure connection, but the file at http://xxx was redirected through an insecure connection. This file should be served over HTTPS. This download has been blocked. See https://blog.chromium.org/2020/02/protecting-users-from-insecure.html for more details.` Shouldn't I be getting error like 
`Mixed Content: The site at https://xxxx was loaded over a secure connection, but the file at https://xxx was NOT available or something.`

Comment: Probably because the browser tried to connect to `https://xxx` but didn't work, so it connected to `http://xxx` instead.